Hollow Knight Questions?

What happens when you die? You respawn at the last bench, but your Life Vessel cracks, what does this mean, you lose your Geo, but can you get it back, I think I heard of a Shade which is when you die?
How do you access the DLC?
How to tell where you are on the Map?



When you die, your soul vessel cracks (so you can only hold 2/3 as much soul as you normally could) and you lose all your geo. You leave behind a "shade", a black ghost thing that wants to kill you. If you find and kill the shade, you get your geo back, and your soul vessel is repaired. You only have one shade at once, and if you die before recovering it, any stored geo is permanently lost.
The DLC installs automatically. See this question for more information.
This is not a question.

Also, please only ask one question at a time.

Yeah sorry I forgot also what happens to crack if you fail? Also I mean actually playing the DLC is far the main game?

@PianoCat98 If you die with your shade gone, there are no further penalties (other than the loss of geo). Your shade will just move to the new location.

@PianoCat98 The DLC integrates seamlessly into the main game. The majority of the content comes in the form of new secrets to find.
